# Nested display lists in openGL

Tags: opengl

I have an openGL display list (let's call it list A) that is compiled using glNewList(ListNum, GL_COMPILE). A second list B is compiled and executed and contains a call to list A.

Then, changes occur in the application that require recompiling list A. Is it safe to assume that this in itself does not require list B to be recompiled? In other words, can I rely on B calling the new version of A although B itself has not been recompiled?

Comment: Don't have time to read up on it myself, but you may want to read the RedBook chapter on display lists, I see a section on hierarchical display lists that may have the answer.  http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter07.html  (it's an old version but I don't think DLists have changed much)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again, Google is my friend. According to http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/displaylist.htm, it works.